# Efficient search for a place on mbtiles data

Tags: mbtiles, search

I have mbtiles data for a country, and display it using GeoServer/OpenLayers. I want to add search functionality to the app, so the user can search for example a street name.

I discovered that GeoServer can perform the search with WFS. But it performs a linear search on the tiles until it finds the feature, which is not the most efficient, but I guess it has no other way since the tile data is serialized, and cannot be indexed that way.

With that said is mbtiles the way to go for searching? If not, what tools are used to have an efficient search, to which I can migrate my mbtiles data?

Comment: I would store the data in PostGIS with indexes for the properties you want to search for and serve the data from GeoServer as mbtiles (or any other format)

Comment: @IanTurton I can now extract the data from the mbtiles, but don't know how the database schema for PostGIS has to be so GeoServer will query the right table/column in that database I'm gonna create.